# Magento 2.2.7 sequence_order_1 after removing database prefix error creating orders

Tags: magento2, database

I'm using Magento 2.2.7, I had a prefix on my tables, e.g: `ab_`, I've removed the prefix on all my database tables via phpmyadmin, and I'm unable to now create orders due to the following error:

```
[2019-02-26 11:52:17] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'site_db.ab_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `ab_sequence_order_1` () VALUES () {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'site_db.ab_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `ab_sequence_order_1` () VALUES () at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MY-SITE/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'site_db.ab_sequence_order_1' doesn't exist at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MY-SITE/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you removed the table_prefix from app/etc/env.php?
Below is reference code:

```
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'db_name',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '123',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Yes, I removed it from there, the homepage, backend, catalog and product views all load fine, the cart loads, and the checkout loads, but when I click on the actual checkout button at the very end of the process it complains about the `site_db.ab_sequence_order_1` being missing, I'm not sure why when generating an order it would still be looking for a prefixed table? It should be worth noting, that I had existing orders in the system before removing the prefix.

Comment: I also get a `Unique constraint violation found` when running the bin/magento setup:upgrade command after renaming the database

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was caused by the `sales_sequence_meta` table requiring to be updated as values inside this table contained prefixed values.